# Azure Bot Add OAUth Connection Settings question

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework, azure-bot-service, microsoft-entra-id

I need to add simple authentication to a bot in azure. My customer wants to

.1 limit the use of an internal chatbot (bot framework V4 in NodeJS running in Azure) to existing AD users.
.2 understand who is using the bot (just first name)

My plan was to first implement it using sample [18. bot-authentication](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication/README.md) and when succesful, implementing it in the real bot.
I am struggling to get past the Add OAUth Connection Settings step in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Caadv2%2Ccsharp#microsoft-entra-id-identity-service)
Testing using Microsoft Entra ID free version in my Azure subscription

Two questions/issues that prevent me from moving forward:

**Question 1.**

The documentation states:

> **Service Provider**. Select **Microsoft Entra ID** to display Microsoft Entra ID-specific field

There is no Microsoft Entra ID option in the drop-down list however. Which one do I select

**Question 2.**

I tried an alternative  option that seams logic to me:

- Name: testService

  provider: Azure Active Directory v2

  Client id: <my client id>

  Client secret: <my client secret>

  Token Exchange URL: <the documentation states "Leave it blank because it's used for SSO in Microsoft Entra ID only." so I leave it blank

  Tenant ID: common

  Scopes: openid profile

When I press *Test Connection* the user is prompted to accept the permissions requested and to enter credentials. After logging in, an error is shown:

> AADSTS500113: No reply address is registered for the application.

What should I enter here?

Any  help is much appreciated

I accepted to be redirected to a **Test Connection to <your-connection-name> Succeeded** page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no Microsoft Entra ID option in the drop-down list however.
> Which one do I select

You need to select *Azure Active Directory v2* as provider for time being till Portal is completely updated with **Microsoft Entra** naming.

> AADSTS500113: No reply address is registered for the application.

This error usually occurs if you missed adding **redirect URL** in your app registration before testing the connection.

I registered one **multi-tenant** application and created one connection setting by selecting *Azure Active Directory v2* as provider like this;

[image]

When I tested the connection without adding redirect URL in application, I too got **same error** as you like below:

[image]

To resolve the error, make sure to add **redirect URLs** in your app registration like this:

```
https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect
https://token.botframework.com
```

[image]

Now, test the connection again which gives **consent prompt** after signing in like this:

[image]

After accepting the consent, it redirected to **Test Connection to 'testService' Succeeded** page:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Supported OAuth URLs - Bot Service | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/ref-oauth-redirect-urls?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)